# Batch file displays error when an in-file location is created

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make an alarm clock batch file and this is the alarm part of the file,

```
:a1
cls
goto invalid
:invalid
if %time%==%t2% goto b
if not %time%==%t2% goto invalid
:b
```

%t2% being the time the alarm should go off, and %time% being the current time; however, when I run this script it displays, "'invalid' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file." I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it does this and doesn't run the script below ":invalid", it just skips to :b.

Comment: I'm quite sure variable `%t2%` is empty, so the `if` statement becomes impaired; use quotation like `if "%time%"=="%t2%"` to avoid that; where and how do you set `%t2%`? do you perhaps have spaces in your `set` statement like `set t2 = ...`, although it should read `set t2=...` or even better `set "t2=..."`? and instead of sequential `if` and `if not` for the same condition you could use `if "%time%"=="%t2%" (...) else (...)`...

Comment: What is the format of your `%time%` variable? This may cause some issues as well.

Comment: the %t2% variable is set before, and the time format is HH:MM:SS.MS(15:15:15.15 for 3:15, and 15.15 seconds) i have done this before, and the t2 is set with a "set /p t2="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and post errors if any:

```
:a1
cls
:invalid
if %time%==%t2% (goto :b
) else ( goto :invalid )
:b
```